# Why Pixel RNN (Row LSTM) can capture triangular contexts?

Tags: deep-learning, recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, deep-neural-networks, deepmind

I'm reading the paper [Pixel Recurrent Neural Network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06759). I have a question about Row LSTM. Why Row LSTM can capture triangular contexts?

In this paper,

> the kernel of the one-dimensional convolution has size $k \times 1$ where $k \geq 3$; the larger value of $k$ the broader the context that is captured.

The one-dimensional kernel can capture only the left context. (Is this correct?)

The $n \times n$ kernel such as

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

can capture triangular contexts.

Is this correct?